# resources for linux programming

Tags: linux

what are the best books or best websites to learn the linux programming for absolute beginners and for professional programmers? To be more specific topics like,
a) forking 
b) Shared memory 
c)exec commands 
d)signals 
e)scheduling algorithms (round robin,first come first serve,priority scheduling,short job first, multilevel queue scheduling, multilevel feedback queue scheduling)

Comment: Not Linux related, but Tanenbaum's “Operating Systems” is a good read.

Comment: I don't think there is anything Linux-specific about any of this. Perhaps a more accurate term would be Unix programming. Is there even a subset of unix programming that is Linux-specific? Nothing comes to mind.

Comment: [Excellent book](http://man7.org/tlpi/); and it's Linux specific (geared towards intermediate to advanced users).

Answer (score 2):

A good book is Advanced Linux Programming, free available [here](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com)

The network programming Holy Bible ;-) : [UNIX network programming V1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131411551)

The IPC programming: [Unix network programming V2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130810819)

the powerful man pages, and some books of Operative systems like either Tannenbaum's [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013230998X) or Stallings' [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136006639) .
However Linux programming = C programming so if I were you also look a good C programming books if you are a beginner.

Comment: +1 Saying that linux programming = C programming is a bit strong (esp. if you don't want to incur the wrath of python heads everywhere), but understanding that it is the fundamental basis of the userspace, and that other forms of programming derive their libraries from its libraries (hence "native C"), is important.

Answer (score 1):

Although the focus is not programming, the [Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/) has been around for more than two decades (according to wikipedia, it was the first linux website online) and contains a lot of fundamental "how-to's" and books.  Some of the material dates back into the previous century and may have limited applicability today, but it is still a great resource.

As mentioned though, the focus is not programming, it's system administration.  You should have a look around for yourself in any case -- the material is eclectic.  The [GNU C Library Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html) (beware that this is not the same as the more basic [GNU C Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html)) does discuss some of your topics in the context of the native library (fork and exec will be in chpt. 26, signals 24).  It doesn't cover threading or shared mem beyond BSD style `mmap()`, since those things aren't part of the base library.

The [POSIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) is mostly a collection of man pages (usually, more informative ones than the linux system ones) that does cover shared mem and threading for POSIX compliant systems (which GNU/linux essentially is).  Man pages are probably the thing I consult most when programming.  They are not always the best *introduction* to a topic, but they are the definitive legalese if you need a specific answer to a specific question.  I find that if I don't understand something very well, stringing enough specific questions together  often makes things clearer than reading someone's rambling exposition on a general topic.